# CSS select first child if it's a certain tag

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

I need to select a particular element only if it occurs as the first child of a div. Is there a CSS selector that'll handle that case?

For example, I want to select this figure:

```
<div>
    <figure></figure>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

But I don't want to select this one:

```
<div>
    <p></p>    
    <figure></figure>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I can't change the HTML, so I can't add a class. I know about the `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` selectors, but they don't fit this case by themselves. How can I select the first child only if it's a figure?

Comment: `div figure:first-child` - http://jsfiddle.net/nvr761d6/

Comment: `:first-child` fits this case *perfectly*..

Comment: To select a `figure` that is the first child *of a div* would require `div > figure:first-child`

Comment: Thanks everybody, great solution! A bunch of people came up with the same answer - ticking Luca's because he seems to have got in first.

Comment: @AndFinally Good for Luca, I was on mobile at the time of writing :-)

Comment: Sorry Hashem, I gave you an upvote!

Comment: @Alohci Can I also update my answer with `>` child selector as you suggested me before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`figure:first-child` will select all the figures that are first child of a parent.

Check this example at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild).

Comment: @Tambo can you explain why is it wrong? He asked how to select the FIGURE tag only if it is the first child and my question solves his issue. I don't see why you don't agree.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Your code highlights the figure even if it is not the first child. Go and check it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use CSS [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector with [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nvr761d6/)**

```
div figure:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

**OR:** with CSS `>` [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (as suggested by [@Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci))

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1xz19xx5/)**

```
div > figure:first-child {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any issue with `figure:first-child` selector. It would select the `<figure>` element **only if** it is the **first child** of its parent.

While `:first-child` represents any element which is the first child in the children tree of the parent,  the `figure` part would limit the selector to match an element only if it is a `<figure>`.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the following?

```
div figure {
    color: green;
}
div figure:first-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `div figure:first-child` selector.

Here is example

```
<div>
    <figure>test</figure>
    <p>div 1 pgraph1</p>
    <p>div 1 pgraph1</p>
</div>

<div>    
    <p>div 2 pgraph1</p>
    <figure>test 2</figure>
    <p>div 2 pgraph1</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div figure:first-child{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

It will apply red border only to first child.

Please refer to **[fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/b4v3px45/1/)**